# How to access a webpage that is constructed using Javascript?

Tags: java, android

How can I access data inside the website that is constructed using Javascript. The login is regular and I use Jsoup, however, when I need to execute built-in javascript, Jsoup doesn't see the final version. Unfortunatelly, Android is not a PC and doesn't allow HtmlUnit to be used (as far as I know).

How do I approach getting data generated by JavaScript without using HtmlUnit?

Comment: What is the problem with HtmlUnit?

Comment: Unfortunately, Android Studio doesn't really allow to use HtmlUnit because it is simulating a browser. Apparently, HtmlUnit is too progressive/resourse-needed to run on a Mobile App.